# I want to use Yandex api translate but

Tags: api, translate

I saw the terms, It's not clear for me if It's for business(ads) or not.

I want if someone can confirm my doubts for me.

If It's not for business can anyone show me other free apis...

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft Text Translate API

[Microsoft Translator Text API](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/translatorapi.aspx)

It has free 2m character translation/month on its free tier

[See Pricing Details here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/translator-text-api/)

And if you are developing your application in android. Might as well help me debug this since I'm trying to create an MS Translator on android. :)

[MS Translator for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47499294/how-to-use-microsoft-translator-api-in-android?noredirect=1#comment82016271_47499294)